# How to change the FontSize in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, font-size, android-fonts

How can you manually change the font size of a webview? e.g. When the page loads up in the webview the font size is like 24pt. and way too large for my android's screen. I've looked into the "websettings" but it seems that the two are not related.

Thanks

Answer (score 106):

I finally found it:-

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
```

either `setTextSize` or

```
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);
```

This one works too:-

```
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(10);
```

Comment: will this work even if  i have specified font size of the text in the html to which the webview is pointing????

Comment: webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST) is deprecated

Comment: How can I do this when building an app via cordova?

Answer (score 40):

It seems that nowadays prefered way, ie not depreciated is to change text zoom, like this:

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setTextZoom(90); // where 90 is 90%; default value is ... 100
```

Answer (score 19):

This is what I use when I want to enable the user to **change the text size / zoom** in a `WebView`:

```
private WebView mWebView;

// init web view and stuff like that ...


private void textSmaller() {

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() - 10);
}

private void textBigger() {

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() + 10);
}
```

On `Actionbar` Item click, I call either `textSmaller()` or `textBigger()` to change the text size.

Answer (score 7):

I use Javascript to  do these kind of things because it practically always works. Even if there are CSS files used in your HTML

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.backgroundColor ='red');");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.color ='yellow');");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.fontSize ='20pt');");
```

ofcourse you need to alter the sizes and colors to the ones you need

Comment: Does not make sense to use `pt` in website. And this answer missed `mWebView.` before `loadUrl()`. Also, loading this line won't change the font size at all, but displaying the font size on screen...

Comment: Remember to set `setJavaScriptEnabled` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase or decrease font Size of WebView dynamycally than use these lines of code:

```
WebView mWebView;
int fontSize;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
    // enable / disable javascript
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    fontSize = mWebView.getSettings().getDefaultFontSize();
}
 private void fontSizePlus() {
    fontSize++;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void fontSizeMinus() {
    fontSize--;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void changeFontSize(int value) {
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(value);
}

public void Inc(View view) {
    fontSizePlus();
}

public void Dec(View view) {
    fontSizeMinus();
}
```