# How to increase font size for webiew in android

Tags: android

How do I increase the font size for webiew in android? I have given the code below, but it's not working. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
blogWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(14);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/android-webview-font-size-change

try doing this with a WebSettings object.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

U can use zoom control in webview. see below code

```
  FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().

    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    final View zoom = this.mWebView.getZoomControls();

    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);

    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);


  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =

    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

    Gravity.BOTTOM);


 webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR)
```