# Programmatically zoom out in an android WebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I need to find a way to programmatically zoom out of a WebView on android. Background: I created a phonegap/cordova web app which has a fixed layout. I am using these settings to proper display of the app across devices:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
this.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.appView.setInitialScale(0);
```

So far it worked well until a text input field gains focus. Then the app gets rescaled and its impossible to return to the proper view. I searched and worked on this problem for over a day now tried many possible solutions but none worked for me. The approach I am working now on is to make a native call when the text input field looses focus and then to reset the zoom. But I don't know a way to reset the zoom.

`webView.zoomOut();` is too slow and `webView.setInitialScale(..);` does nothing.

I am looking for something like `webView.setZoomLevel(..);` or `webView.setScale(..);` but I can not find it in the api.

Pulling out my hair about this.. Please help.

BTW, my meta viewport setting is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,height=device-height,target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/android-webview-font-size-change

Comment: That answer does not apply here. It is about text size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No answer for this question. I guess there is just no way to set the zoom level other than zooming out using the `zoomOut()` function. So I had to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Does one of the responses in this question help?
[How to set the initial zoom/width for a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview)

Brian first suggested: webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
and then littleFluffyKitty added: using setInitialScale(50) along with other zoom settings.

Good luck and I hope someone with more wisdom than I have gives you a better answer.

Comment: no. As I wrote below I did not find a solution so I had to live with a workaround.