# Android Studio Default Font Size

Tags: android-studio

I have created an app in android studio. In my phone settings when I make the default font size bold and big. App won't work properly.

I just have a webview in xml.

How can I set default text size in a activity?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If I am not wrong [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796176/5180017) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, this one works. Thank you.